# Linking to a template file relatively in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am trying to run a ajax post script from the header of a wordpress site on an action.

I am currently using

```
bloginfo('template_directory')
```

to get a link to where the script is. But the above currently outputs

```
http://domain.com/wp-themes/path/to/file.php
```

but what I need to run the script is the relative version

```
../../../wp-themes/path/to/file.php
```

and ths will be different depending on the depth of the post / page.

Is there a modifier in wordpress anywhere to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

The 'template_directory' attribute for the `bloginfo()` function will always return a URL.
You were probably looking for something like

```
get_template_directory()
```

Comment: Have tried 

"<?php get_template_directory(); ?>/comment_notification.php"

and all it displays in the code is 

"/comment_notification.php"

Is there something else i need to do to make sure this reference works

Comment: You need to add echo in front of the function call. 

<?php echo get_template_directory(); ?>/comment_notification.php